# when I use isset($_SESSION['name']) and I can't get the value in website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

my config wrote:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH.'public/sess_save_path';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH.'sessions';
```

when I wrote this script it is same too.

but when I set path with '', it is an error found.
I am using CodeIgniter in Heroku.
I do not know how to set the config in Heroku.

it is an error in the beginning?

```
session_start();
class Users extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Users_model');
        $this->load->library('session');

    }
```

help me!

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'd expect to see `$_SESSION` in your code example and knowledge that `session_start()` has been called before trying to use the session variable.

Comment: when I add session_start() to the script, it will show an error by 'started always'